# Yii 1 query return incorrect data

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, yii1.x

I have query:

```
$listings = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM listings')->where(['or like','c_sales_stage',['Needs Refresh','Active']])->andWhere('c_listing_featured_c = 1')->queryAll();
```

Returns all the listings even where c_listing_featured_c is 0.
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: add your generated sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) says:

**Note: Query builder cannot be used to modify an existing query specified as a SQL statement. For example, the following code will not work:**

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl_user');
// the following line will NOT append WHERE clause to the above SQL
$command->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));
```

To solve your problem remove argument from `createCommand()` function and add `from()` in chain:

```
$listings = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->from('listings')
   //->where()       //here your where condition
   ->andWhere('c_listing_featured_c = 1')
   ->queryAll();
```